# When is ViewState session cleared ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, viewstate, session-state

I know SessionState is Cleared when the session dies - usually after 20min of inactivity.
 My question is when does ViewState session dies ? Or does it never dies ? Is there any way to clear it ?

Comment: In addition to the answers below.. you can also just issue a `Response.Redirect` to the same URL.

Comment: Is exist inside the page, is dies if you go to some other page, is show up on code behind if you make post back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Viewstate lasts for as long as it's on the page - it's outputted with the HTML; check the source to your rendered page and you will see a load of text in a hidden field.

Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNTIyODQ4NzI.....
```

Once the page is gone, it's gone.

You can clear it by calling

```
ViewState.Clear()
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. You answered my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as answered - helps everybody else in the future too :) and keeps your accept-rate up (which means people will help you more in the future too :) )

Comment: You mean when the user closes the browser it is gone ?

Answer (score 1):

Old ViewState, like [old soldiers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdoQhEqzAb4), never dies, it just fades away...

It's stored in hidden fields in the HTML page, and stays alive in the browser's cache.